# using a variablename of a class that is initializising

Tags: java, class, variables, initialization

i want to initialize a class and while doing this i want to use the classvariable.

like this:

```
Myclass name = new Myclass(new AnotherClass(name));
```

it says: The local variable name may not have been initialized.
so my question is if there is a way to let AnotherClass know all the functions that MyClass has.

Comment: If you're using it like that, with that being the first use of Myclass name, then its may not have been initialized, it **has not** been initialised. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: i want that AnotherClass can use all the methods of MyClass

Comment: First thing which will be invoked is new AnotherClass(name), so it's telling you to first initialize name. Put Myclass name in upper row and initialize it with null.

Comment: If you want AnotherClass to have the same methods as MyClass then make AnotherClass extend MyClass

Comment: I think you have a serious design problem. Rethink your design.

Comment: @Matej If you're going to do that you might as well pass null directly, it will not create 2 way linked objects

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't have both objects require each other to construct them.  Not only will this not work it is poor design.

If you really need something like this, create on object by itself:

```
Myclass name = new Myclass();
```

Then when you create AnotherClass pass it MyClass and have it save a reference to it.

```
name.setAnohterClass(new AnotherClass(name));
```

Better design would be to have less coupling and just have one class know about the other.  For example:

```
Myclass name = new Myclass();
AnotherClass another = new AnotherClass(name);
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to let other class only know about functions (not object state), you can use other object with deault constructor to make it:

```
Myclass tmpObject = new Myclass();
Myclass name = new Myclass(new AnotherClass(tmpObject));
```

But I also recommend to review `AnotherClass`. This is not clear what function you want to use, may be you can use them `static`, so you should not pass them to `Myclass` object.

Comment: Thanks, I am use them now as `static`.

Answer (score 1):

Try

`Myclass name = new Myclass(new AnotherClass(new Myclass()));`

The problem is you are trying to initialize object `name` from source object `name` itself. Which is not possible, you know that now.

If you want to achieve, you can do as above.